# Non-Working paintComponent method

Tags: java, jpanel, paintcomponent

Code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class firstGUI extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame =  new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Image image = new ImageIcon("dist.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image,0,0, this);
    }
}
```

Compiles perfectly, but when I run it, it just shows a form. No picture(or any other operation in `paintComponent`) shows up. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `paintComponent` method is an instance method of your `firstGUI` class (a `JPanel`). The problem is that you are not creating an instance of `firstGUI` and adding it to the frame.

The following replacement `main` method instantiates `firstGUI` and adds it to the `contentPane` of the frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new firstGUI());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```